# Why am I getting an error in mlogit() but not when I add +0 for no intercept for individual specific variables?

Tags: r, mlogit

I'm trying to analyze some data using mlogit. I get an error saying"
Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.18087e-27"

`(choice~1|v1+v2+...vn, data, shape="long",alt.var="Mode",choice="Choice")`

Although, when I add +0 in the second part of the formulae(individual specific variables), thus requiring no intercepts for the coefficients, I get no error.

`mlogit(choice~1|v1+v2+...vn+0, data, shape="long",alt.var="Mode",choice="Choice")`

The summary looks like this:

```
Call:
mlogit(formula = Choice ~ 1 | +0 + fromSYR + fromNYC + fromALB + 
    DistSYR + DistNYC + DistALB + SafteyPersonal + SafteyTrainBus + 
    SafteyCarpool + SafteyTaxi + SafteySharedTaxi + PrivacyPersonal + 
    PrivacyTrainBus + PrivacyCarpool + PrivacyTaxi + PrivacySharedTaxi + 
    ConviniencePersonal + ConvinienceTrainBus + ConvinienceCarpool + 
    ConvinienceTaxi + ConvinienceSharedTaxi + TimePersonal + 
    TimeTrainBus + TimeCarpool + TimeTaxi + TimeSharedTaxi + 
    flightsYear + daysBreturn + luggage + ownVehicle + incomeB + 
    familySize + ageB + shuttleMaxPersonsB + payUticaSYR + payUticaALB, 
    data = Ta, method = "nr")

Frequencies of alternatives:
 Carpool Personal     Taxi TrainBus 
 0.31250  0.43750  0.21875  0.03125 

nr method
20 iterations, 0h:0m:0s 
g'(-H)^-1g = 7.46E-07 
gradient close to zero 

Coefficients :

.....

Log-Likelihood: -2.7444e-07
```